# missing inserted endgroup

Tags: math-mode, equations

I'm typing this equation

```
\eta=\frac{82\cdot4\cdot1.44 \textrm{MeV}\cdot10$^-15$\textrm{m}}{2\cdot6.582\cdot 10$^-10$ \textrm{MeV}\cdot\textrm{s}\cdot0.0774\cdot2.998\cdot10$^8$\textrm{ms$^-1$}}
```

and I'm not able to find the mistake.

Comment: You don't need the additional switch to math-mode for superscipts like `$^{10}$`. Just use `^{10}` or `^{-15}`. Note the braces to group the entire thing that needs to go in the superscript.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Since you haven't accepted a single answer, I don't expect you to do it here, either, but one can hope...

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%  locale = DE,% comma instead of full stop as decimal separator
  exponent-product = \cdot,
  inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \eta
  = \frac{82 \cdot 4 \cdot \SI{1.44}{\MeV} \cdot \SI{e-15}{\m}}% numerator
         {2 \cdot \SI{6.582e-10}{\MeV\s} \cdot \num{0.0774} \cdot \SI{2.998e8}{\m\per\s}}% denominator
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]